# Iterator that skips every nth element

Tags: rust

Rather than *taking* every Nth element from an iterator which I can do with [`Iterator::step_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by), I would like to *skip* every Nth element. How can I achieve this idiomatically? Is there maybe even a standard library or `itertools` function?

This is what I came up with to skip every 7th say. It requires `enumerate`, `filter`, and `map`, though one could use a `filter_map` instead of the latter two.

```rust
(0..100).enumerate()
      .filter(|&(i, x)| (i + 1) % 7 != 0)
      .map(|(i, x)| x);
```

How could I cast this into a function so that I could simply write:

```rust
(0..100).skip_every(7)
```

Comment: Other than writing a custom iterator adapter? I don't think there is a way, not in `std` or `itertools`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the exact interface you asked for, your best option at this time is to implement a custom iterator adapter type. Here's a basic version of such a type:

```
pub struct SkipEvery<I> {
    inner: I,
    every: usize,
    index: usize,
}

impl<I> SkipEvery<I> {
    fn new(inner: I, every: usize) -> Self {
        assert!(every > 1);
        let index = 0;
        Self {
            inner,
            every,
            index,
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for SkipEvery<I> {
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index == self.every - 1 {
            self.index = 1;
            self.inner.nth(1)
        } else {
            self.index += 1;
            self.inner.next()
        }
    }
}

pub trait IteratorSkipEveryExt: Iterator + Sized {
    fn skip_every(self, every: usize) -> SkipEvery<Self> {
        SkipEvery::new(self, every)
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator + Sized> IteratorSkipEveryExt for I {}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f36a23a4d8fb49772ad9fd91fd5e040c))

A more complete implementation could also add optimized versions of further `Iterator` methods, as well as implementations of `DoubleEndedIterator` and `ExactSizeIterator` -- see [the implementation of `StepBy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/step_by.rs.html) as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is pretty easy to turn into a function:

```
fn skip_every<I: Iterator> (iter: I, n: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = <I as Iterator>::Item> {
    iter.enumerate()
        .filter_map(move |(i, v)| if (i + 1) % n != 0 { Some (v) } else { None })
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", skip_every (0..20, 7).collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=1924a2227f12e686eaa291e56041ca25)

Or avoiding the expensive modulo:

```
fn skip_every2<I: Iterator> (iter: I, n: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = <I as Iterator>::Item> {
    iter.zip ((0..n).rev().cycle()).filter_map (|(v, i)| if i != 0 { Some (v) } else { None })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=7e9d834dca09296155b66561b4366edf)

Comment: I believe OP wanted a new method on iterators rather than a free standing function.

Comment: @cafce25 ideally yes, an iterator adaptor would be ideal so that it could be used just like `step_by`, chained after an `.iter()`

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be used in an extension trait because [`impl` generics are not allowed in trait method return types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/labels/F-return_position_impl_trait_in_trait) and because the return type can't be named due to the map closure. So you would need to define your own iterator struct.

Comment: While it's nightly only it [still works here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=393f0222e5b456b07507439090ea9848)